# Coudnt retrieve the graphical layout

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, android-layout

This is my activity_main.xml.
when I try to switch to the graphical view, it says Pick a fragment from the "Fragment Layout" menu.

Plus, neither the button nor the spinner shows up in my layout !!!!!

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 tools:context=".MainActivity" >

  <Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spr_place_type"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"  />

  <Button
     android:id="@+id/btn_find"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/spr_place_type"
    android:text="@string/str_btn_find" />

  <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/spr_place_type"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

  </RelativeLayout>
```

Can anyone solve this problem for me ?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the fragment namespace.

```
<fragment
android:id="@+id/map"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@id/spr_place_type"
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

Comment: yes its no longer there.. but how am i suppose to include maps into my layout if I remove the fragment part?

Comment: Copy what I have put and replace your fragment with it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's just information for the Graphical Layout editor how the fragment should be displayed in the editor.

try to remove

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

and try

Comment: still the same bro =(

Comment: @StenlyJoseph but you can ignore that..because it won't be an issue for building your app

Comment: are you sure bout it bro? thanks anyway.. btw i cnt get the spinner n the button on my layout as well